# Local Users and Groups MVC Intranet Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using the following definition in my Web.Config.

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

I added a new Group and made my login a member of that group. Then, when I queried the System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(), I didn't see the group in the result.

I am using the Local Users and Groups Dialog.

[image]

The second question, How can I get the name and description for all groups the current user belongs too?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Hi Looks like your DNS may not have been updated. Either you can restart your dns services by going to services or you can simply logout and log back in to get the update. Try that should work :)

For your 2nd question here is the answer :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ak75t41(v=vs.110).aspx

you can do
    Roles.GetRolesForUser() and it will return an array of roles for the user.

Comment: That is what I used Roles.GetRolesForUser(). It is not returning anyones that I manually created.

Comment: have you logged out and logged back in? or have you restarted your DNS?

Comment: Restarting did it..However now  I am even more concerned. This negates the fact the users can be added/dropped anytime and RolesProvider doesn't query windows.

Comment: It actually depends on how your active directory is setup, you can setup your server to do the group policy update as frequent as you can. you can even force update the policy by running this command (gpupdate /force). you can read more here (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490983.aspx)